# How to explain high collar cloak's ability to withstand daylight when vampire undergoes transformation from bat's form?

Tags: fantasy-races, shapeshifters, vampires

The following is extracted from an account of a man proclaimed to be the last surviving member of the Hellsing clan which is so secretive that it buffers the Illuminati till today regarding their purposes and how their organisation operates:

Dear Prof Abraham,

I need to tell you what I have found out today, I saw the transformation of a vampire into bat on multiple occasions. They(vampy) would usually flew into an occupied houses at midnight as a bat and then transformed into seemingly a human form always with a high collar cloak on, once I fought with one of them until daybreak but the vampire managed to run off into the dark alley. I saw that the subject used the cloak to block out the sunlight while sprinting off, fortunately I managed to pull off a small piece of the cloak and suddenly it turns into some kind of skins and muscles... yuck! Since you never believe in magic and I think we should find out how the cloak works so I need your expertise on this matter urgently.

Hope to hear from you soon, stay home and always wash your hands.

Regards,
Someone from Hellsing Clan

Comment: I think we need to know more about your setting.    Your professor doesn't believe in magic but does that mean that your vampires are really not magical?  Purely biological vampires are not unheard of, but authors who use them usually downplay the aversion to holy relics and the whole conflagration by sunlight aspects of the condition.  So are you asking for your professor's narrow minded explanation of an aspect which is really magical in origin, or are you asking for a mundane, purely biological explanation to sunlight induced spontaneous combustion?

Comment: Also, what level of science does your professor have available to him?  What era is your story set in?

Comment: I mean, you yourself said the character believes it to be magic, and I don't remember any real life example of organic tissue seemingly turning into fabric. Maybe, since it can clearly change faster than it ever should, the process involves the production of a protective layer of silk-like fur, which is so dense (and white in color, as that reflects more light) it blocks all wavelengths from sunlight altogether, preventing the cloak's vampire cells to be exposed to it, similar to how an otter usually never gets its skin wet thanks to the thick layer of fur it has.

Comment: Humanoid vampire to bat transformation violates conservation of mass principle, so we can't avoid magic here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(And by God I think our penchant for compartmentalization has gotten excessive now that we have to refer to people by numbers...)

I would be exceedingly interested in receiving a sample of tissue you obtained, hopefully you have preserved it in as pure an alcohol is locally availible and in a dark bottle to protect the specimen from light. I fear it may degrade substantially before reaching me.

Based on yours and other reports, I have a hypothesis that there may be symbiotic organism that is being bred or cultivated by our pale adversies. My colleagues scoff at this idea, but I am convinced, that we somehow lack a vital piece of information in understanding the movements of vampires. From our contact tracing studies, we are fairly certain that somehow there is more daylight movement of vampires than we previously assumed.

My hypothesis is that the symbioite, if it exists, like the black wings of certain moths has certain light trapping structures to absorb the light in an exceedingly thin and flexible layer and converts the sunlight into heat. While this would limit the time the symbioite could withstand the sunlight it would afford temporary protection for its host.

It could be that somehow there is a special fabric that is used for cloaks, but my own experiments show that the weaves of most fabrics are porous, or transparent enough to sunlight that (unless wrapped in multiple, cumbersome layers much like a mummy with movement severely restricted) that they would provide little protection. Our pale adversaries are much too graceful to be thus encumbered.

Another specimen, so degraded as to be virtually useless, was provided to me, and in that account it was mentioned, that the cloak moved strangely and rippling almost independently. In that case the vampire was slain and in the sunlight both the vampire and the majority of the cloak was rapidly consumed in the usual exothermic reaction. Perhaps the light trapping layer was breached and the underlying organism shares similar characteristics as a vampire and was consumed in a similar way.

Given that new vampires don't often appear in cloaks, and our observation that only very old vampires have some ability to walk in daylight, my thought is if the cloak is organic it must somehow increase in size and grow and the vampire ages. My assumption is that the vampire must somehow be cultivating and sustaining it. Hence, like other examples we see in nature as in certain slime moulds that feed off of leaf litter and the dead, my thoughts have turned to there being some type of symbiotic relationship that has developed. My thought is that the "cloak membrane creature" must somehow derive certain benefits from the vampire and vice versa the vampire obtains the benefit of mobility in sunlight.

The mere mention of "magic" no longer winds me up as it once did. My certainly in  the natural order of things and the value of science is firm.

Washing hands, as normal.

Stay safe,

Your Prof.